# individual string list to list of string

Tags: python-3.x, function, nlp

I have a text output that has individual list,this format ['a']['b']['c'] and so on and I want to convert this list into a string put in a list, in this format ['a','b','c'].The end goal is to create a new column and append this list of strings to rows in a column.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I have a list of this format ['a']['b']['c'] ,I need it in this format ['a','b','c']

Answer (score 1):

You can join the lists like this:

```
list_item = [['a'], ['b'], ['c']]
result = []
for i in list_item:
    result.append(i[0])

print(result)
```

The result will be this:

```
['a', 'b', 'c']
```

Comment: Thank you but the format is this ['a']['b']['c'] , not this [['a'], ['b'], ['c']] I need it in this format ['a','b','c']

Comment: hi @deedee In terms of python syntax, such an output=['a']['b']['c'] is not possible.Can you show me how this output is generated?